# How to keep object state in electron/node.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, electron

I'm trying to create a Database class using node.js mysql module.

The point is, I want to be able to use the class in different files. But the class itself should keep one connection persistent. So I need somehow to keep object state between files.

My code so far:

main.js

```
const database = require('./app/database.js');

//// somewhere later in BrowserWindow initianisation
database.init(config);
```

custom_file.js

```
const database = require('./app/database.js');

setInterval(
    () => {
        updateOrdersTable();
    }
    , 10000
);

function updateOrdersTable() {
    console.log('updateOrdersTable');

    database.getCurrentOrders((orders) => {
        orders.forEach((row) => {
            console.log(row);
        });
    });
}
```

app/database.js

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

class Database {
  config = {};
  connection = {};
  customerWindow = {};
  stockWindow = {};

  init(config) {

    this.config = config;

    process.stdout.write('Connecting to MySQL Server...');

    this.connect();
  }

    connect() {
      this.connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: this.config.database.host,
        port: this.config.database.port,
        user: this.config.database.user,
        password: this.config.database.password,
        database: this.config.database.database
      });

      const that = this;
      this.connection.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Database error', err);

          setTimeout(that.connect, that.config.database.reconnect_interval * 1000);
          return;
        }
    
        console.log('Success!');
      });
    
      this.connection.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('Database error', err);

        setTimeout(that.connect, that.config.database.reconnect_interval * 1000);
      });
    }

    getCurrentOrders(callback) {
      this.connection.query("SELECT * FROM current_orders", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;

        callback(result)
      });
    }
}

module.exports = new Database();
```

The error message I'm getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.connection.query is not a function
    at Database.getCurrentOrders (F:\my-app\app\database.js:91)
```

Line 91 is this:

```
this.connection.query("SELECT * FROM current_orders", function (err, result, fields) {
```

Comment: Clearly the execution context is being changed. in 'complex.js` my guess is that `database.getCurrentOrders()` is _actually_ called in sometype of async function or from within an arrow function.

Comment: Sounds like you're asking for a singleton, but my first question would be: Are you sure `init` is being called before `getCurrentOrders` ?

Comment: @RandyCasburn you are right I run it in setInterval function every 10 seconds to update the list.

@jlogan Yes I am sure the init function is called first, because I call it in ```function createWindow () {``` which is just called in ```app.whenReady().then(createWindow)```

Comment: You'll need to bind the call to `database.getCurrentOrders()` to the instance of `database` like so: `database.getCurrentOrders().bind(database);` -- that should do it.

Comment: I mean specifically in your setTimeout bit.

Comment: Didn't work. Think I will try that Singleton pattern..

Comment: it already is a Singleton. That's how modules work natively. You've assigned the only instance of your class to be exported. No other instantiation occurs. The problem is with the context changing because you are calling the function from a callback. Share the code that contains the interval timer and calls `database.getCurrentOrders()`

Comment: @slawkens in Electron it's possible to have a singleton initialised in the "main" instance but not in the "renderer" instance, or vice versa. How are you loading `custom_file.js` in the app?

Comment: @RandyCasburn oh, didn't knew that.I already included that code by editing the main post. Its the custom_file.js

@Matt custom_file.js is in renderer instance, as I include it in my HTML code as follows: ```<script>
        require('./custom_file.js');
    </script>```

So basically I want to share an instance to renderer process.

Comment: Basically I need a class for my database queries. I don't need them in main.js, I need them just in my renderer process. If I rewrite the code, and call it only in my randerer processes will it work?